# ¿Cómo puedo reducir a dos decimales y separar?

Tags: python

Hola amigos de Stack Over tengo el siguiente número declarado en la siguiente variable:

```
número = 2.1215x10^07
```

Sin embargo, tengo dos interrogantes:

¿Cómo podría reducirlo a dos decimales?

¿Cómo podría reconocer la x y separar 2.1215 de 10^07?

Comment: Ese no es un string ...

Comment: Ups! lo editare, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si `numero` fuera un string:

```
numero = "2.1215x10^07"
print(numero.split("x")[0])
```

usas `split("x")` para dividirlo en dos por la letra "x". Eso te retorna una lista de dos elementos ("2.1215", "10^07"), de la cual tomas el primero usando "[0]"

Sólo queremos dos decimales, asi que convertirmos la mantisa con `float` y luego `round` a dos decimales:

```
mantisa = round(float(numero.split("x")[0]), 2)
print(mantisa)
```

produce:

```
2.12
```

Comment: muchas gracias mi estimado amigo